# How to do initialization and assignment separately for std::istringstream and move in below case?

Tags: c++

`std::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));` this initialize declare and move result_string in one shot as per what I understood. Later I use it like this:

```
while (iss >> result_string)
```

But I want to declare `iss` and then `move()` separately. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move a string into a stringstream at all. Yes, you can type `std::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));` all you want, but it will *not* move the string into the stream. It will copy it. Not unless your `stringstream` implementation has some non-standard addition to it.

You can re-initialize a stringstream at any time by using the `str` function:

```
istringstream theStream(...);

//stuff

theStream.str(result_string); //Stream reinitialized.
```

If you want to wrap that in `std::move` to make yourself feel better, you can. But it still won't move from it. `move` is not a magical salve that causes things to be moved; it's just a fancy type-cast. The actual movement happens via constructors, and stringstreams do not have constructors that can move from `std::string` objects.

Comment: thanks. So`std::istringstream iss; iss.str(result_string);` is equivalent to `td::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));`?

Comment: Every real implementation of std::string is copy-on-write, so ss.str(s) doesn't cause the string data to be deep copied.  Just be sure not to modify the original string after you've given it to an istringstream, or it'll make a copy when you do.

Comment: @GlennMaynard: "*Every real implementation of std::string is copy-on-write*" That's not even *remotely* true. Visual Studio has *never* used COW strings. libc++ has *never* used COW strings. And even libstdc++ abandoned them because COW strings were *banned* by C++11's updated rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream::str()` to set the internal buffer. Since the `std::string` is always taken by `const&` you can safely omit the `std::move()`: internally, the storage used in `std::stringbuf` is *not* a `std::string`:

```
iss.str(result_string);
```

Comment: @Diermar: So`std::istringstream iss; iss.str(result_string);` is equivalent to `td::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));`?

Comment: @Karimkhan: Yes. There is no `str()` overload taking a `std::string&&` but only one taking a `std::string const&`. After all, the stream won't use the `std::string` anyway and just copy the characters into its internal buffer (with `std::string` now being guaranteed to represent their value using contiguous memory it would be possible for `std:stringbuf` to internally use a `std::string` mostly but the stream buffers want to provide unused space, at least, for output but the buffer is shared between input and output).